# Why android studio autocompletes stops when using Future keyword in dart

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

I use Android Studio version 3.6.3.
I'm building an app using flutter.

When I type Future keyword, Android Studio autocompletes stops. So, I have to restart the Android Studio.

Sometimes, I should restart it several times. I don't know how to resolve it.

Is there anyone who can help me? Thanks for your help.

Sorry for my English